# PHP | xdebug 3 + phpstorm

Tags: php, ubuntu, сервер, phpstorm, xdebug

Знаю, что вопрос избитый, но я в отчаянии. Просмотрел и заюзал десятки статей и видео на ютубе, но ничто не помогло его настроить. Либо где-то у меня настроено было изначально не так, то ли какую-то важную мелочь упускал, не знаю.

Что имею:
ubuntu server 20 (на vmware, подключение через sftp),
php 7.4,
xdebug 3

в файле php.ini следующие настройки (по новому стандарту из статьи https://losst.ru/nastrojka-xdebug-v-phpstorm):

```
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
xdebug.discover_client_host = false
xdebug.client_host = 192.168.48.128
xdebug.client_port = 9000
```

Скрины настроек: [PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcEoC.png) | [Proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IvY6.png) | [Servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5eGV.png)

Так же скачивал расширение xdebug helper, но слышал, что он не так и нужен. Можно ж без него обойтись?

Answer (score 0):

```
[xdebug]

xdebug.mode                      = debug
xdebug.client_host              = "localhost"
xdebug.client_port              = 9003
xdebug.discover_client_host     = true
xdebug.start_with_request       = "yes"
```

Для vscode OS: win10, debian

Comment: Попробовал, но теперь при validate вот что пишет [validate](https://i.imgur.com/rzUMh7K.png)

Comment: xdebug.client_host              = "0.0.0.0" попробуй